# extract wsdl password from soap ui project xml

Tags: eclipse, soap, wsdl, soapui, wsimport

I have been given a url to a password protected wsdl and told to develop from it. The only other resource I have is a project setup xml for soap ui. The document works and I am able to import the project into soap ui and connect to the wsdl that way. I can even run operations. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out what the password is, so I have no way to view the wsdl directly, or (more importantly) have soap ui autogenerate the java client code.

I have found two usernames used in the xml document, but they are all used for individual operations. Putting them into my browser has not worked. Are there a wsdl username and password hidden somewhere in the soap ui document?

I also don't think I fully grasp the auth file thing. I went to USER_HOME and made a .metro folder, then put an extensionless file called "auth" in it and put "http://userName:password@remoteHost.wsdl?wsdl", but eclipse continued to ask for the auth file as though it did not exist.

Comment: SoapUI stores all passwords in plaintext in the project.xml file.